# In gitorious, is it possible to move repositories to a different project?

Tags: gitorious

We have a bunch of small projects that have a single repository in Gitorious.  Most of these repositories are really related.  Had the foresight been put into the original creation, these would have all been created under the same project.

Now that there is all of this sprawl, is there any way to keep the repositories (or at least their history) intact, yet group them under a new project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such move option in gitorious.
The only way I know is to create a new repository inside the target project and then push the code to this repository. Afterwards, you can delete the repository. Note: moving the repository will update the associated URL. This will require coordinating the new URL with any local clones.